# BAT File: Running new command prompt from bat file

Tags: batch-file

How would I go about running a new command prompt window from a bat file and then having 2 arguments in that new window? (change title and echo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
start "" /d "." %windir%\System32\cmd.exe /k "echo something && title AAA"
```